# Updating the DOM to recognize AJAX inserted inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm pretty much an idiot when it comes to AJAX, so if this problem is really simple, please forgive me.

I have this little form:

```
<form id="location_ajax_request">
  <label for="location">Enter Your Location:</label>
  <input name="ajax_location" id="ajax_location" type="text" value="Irvine, CA, USA" />
  <input id="requestLocation" type="button" value="Click to Submit" />
  <p id="output"></p>
</form>
```

When `requestLocation` is clicked, a `GET` call to a php script returns something like:

```
<input type="radio" name="location_selected" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="location_x_0" value="-117.8253403" />
<input type="hidden" name="location_y_0" value="33.6868782" />
<input type="hidden" name="location_name_0" value="Irvine, CA, USA" />
[...]
<input type="button" id="confirmAddress" value="Confirm Address" />
```

Where the `_0` is a count of items. If, for instance, someone had entered London, USA, they'd receive some 5 responses.

With jQuery, I grab the click of `$('#confirmAddress')` successfully using `live()` and attempt to grab the values of the inputs. I assume they somehow need to be checked for since inserted elements aren't registered with the DOM. Say I'm trying to grab:

```
document.forms['location_ajax_request']['location_name_0'].value;
```

How do I first register it with the DOM as a valid object so it stops returning undefined?

Comment: Are you successfully adding the input controls to the page? If so they are in the dom already.

Comment: Yes, I am, but they weren't appearing to be registered. They simply respond "undefined".

Comment: I don't think your selector above is correct. As evidenced by the answer below. :)

Comment: If I hardcoded the `<input>` tags as above and attempted to grab the value, it worked fine. For whatever reason, dynamically generating them was not allowing me to access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) as the OP tags say:

```
$('input[name="location_name_0"]', '#location_ajax_request').val();
```

Comment: @stslavik no problem ^_^ happy to help